# Jquery refuses to select an element using the correct syntax

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href

Hi i wanted to remove a link and i got this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".features-list a").removeAttr("href");
```

And is not selecting the element

```
<ul class="features-list">
<li id="f1"><a href="http://www.somepage.com"Link that stops being a link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I added the id to try and see if i could do this

```
 $(".features-list#f1").removeAttr("href");
```

Is not working, i must add that the rest of the jquery code is being correctly executed, i just can't figure this one out. This is all i tried to remove the link

```
 $("#f1").removeAttr("href");
 $(".features-list > a").removeAttr("href");
 $(".features-list li ").removeAttr("href");
 $(".features-list").children(a).removeAttr("href");
```

I even tried

```
 $(".features-list").Attr("href","#");
```

But jquery refuses to select it
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: if you're using firefox, there a `html validation` plugin https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link appears broken (it's missing the closing tag `>`):

```
<a href="http://www.somepage.com"Link that stops being a link</a>
```

It should be:

```
<a href="http://www.somepage.com">Link that stops being a link</a>
```

Also `$(".features-list#f1").removeAttr("href");` didn't work because there's no `href` attribute defined on the `li` and this li has no `class="features-list"`.

`$('#f1 a')` selects a link which is inside an element with `id="f1"` (which is the `li` in your case). `$(".features-list a").removeAttr("href")` should also work.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sXhKD/1/).

Comment: I don't think i know selectors just yet, i'll keep stuydying them. I randomnly tried different strings and this one worked
$("#f1 a").removeAttr("href");